# React Native Shuffling songs in Music player using React-Native-Video

Tags: react-native

So I am making a music player and used react-native-video. For my output, I am able to play all the songs that I added it into the `App.js` where the data is `Track`. But I am able to change songs but not able to shuffle the music player when I press the forward button. Even when I toggled it on. I am not my error that does not allow me to shuffle them.

This is my `Player` Component

```
import Controls from './Controls';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

export default class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  paused: true,
  totalLength: 1,
  currentPosition: 0,
  selectedTrack: 0,
  repeatOn: false,
  shuffleOn: true,
};
  }

  setDuration(data) {
// console.log(totalLength);
this.setState({totalLength: Math.floor(data.duration)});
}

  setTime(data) {
//console.log(data);
this.setState({currentPosition: Math.floor(data.currentTime)});
  }

  seek(time) {
time = Math.round(time);
this.refs.audioElement && this.refs.audioElement.seek(time);
this.setState({
  currentPosition: time,
  paused: false,
});
  }

  onBack() {
if (this.state.currentPosition < 10 && this.state.selectedTrack > 0) {
  this.refs.audioElement && this.refs.audioElement.seek(0);
  this.setState({ isChanging: true });
  setTimeout(() => this.setState({
    currentPosition: 0,
    paused: false,
    totalLength: 1,
    isChanging: false,
    selectedTrack: this.state.selectedTrack - 1,
  }), 0);
} else {
  this.refs.audioElement.seek(0);
  this.setState({
    currentPosition: 0,
  });
}
  }

  onForward() {
if (this.state.selectedTrack < this.props.tracks.length - 1) {
  this.refs.audioElement && this.refs.audioElement.seek(0);
  this.setState({ isChanging: true });
  setTimeout(() => this.setState({
    currentPosition: 0,
    totalLength: 1,
    paused: false,
    isChanging: false,
    selectedTrack: this.state.selectedTrack + 1,
  }), 0);
}
  }



  render() {
const track = this.props.tracks[this.state.selectedTrack];
const video = this.state.isChanging ? null : (
  <Video source={{uri: track.url}} // Can be a URL or a local file.
    ref="audioElement"
    paused={this.state.paused}               // Pauses playback entirely.
    resizeMode="cover"           // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.
    repeat={false}                // Repeat forever.
    onLoadStart={this.loadStart} // Callback when video starts to load
    onLoad={this.setDuration.bind(this)}    // Callback when video loads
    onProgress={this.setTime.bind(this)}    // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime
    onEnd={this.onEnd}           // Callback when playback finishes
    onError={this.videoError}    // Callback when video cannot be loaded
    style={styles.audioElement} />
);

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Controls
      onPressRepeat={() => this.setState({repeatOn : !this.state.repeatOn})}
      repeatOn={this.state.repeatOn}
      shuffleOn={this.state.shuffleOn}
      forwardDisabled={this.state.selectedTrack === this.props.tracks.length - 1}
      onPressShuffle={() => this.setState({shuffleOn: !this.state.shuffleOn})}
      onPressPlay={() => this.setState({paused: false})}
      onPressPause={() => this.setState({paused: true})}
      onBack={this.onBack.bind(this)}
      onForward={this.onForward.bind(this)}
      paused={this.state.paused}/>
    {video}
  </View>
);
  }
}
```

This is my `CSS`

```
const styles = {
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: 'rgb(4,4,4)',
},
audioElement: {
height: 0,
width: 0,
}
};
```

And this is my `App.js` Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Player from './Player';

export const TRACKS = [
{
id: '1',
url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Post_Malone_-_Better_Now.mp3',
title: 'Better Now',
artist: 'Post Malone',
artwork: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c1/Beerbongs_%26_Bentleys_by_Post_Malone.png/220px-Beerbongs_%26_Bentleys_by_Post_Malone.png'
    },
{
id: '2',
url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Luis_Fonsi_feat._Daddy_Yankee_-_Despacito.mp3',
title: 'Despacito',
artist: 'Luis Fonsi',
artwork:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c8/Luis_Fonsi_Feat._Daddy_Yankee_-_Despacito_%28Official_Single_Cover%29.png'
},
{
id: '3',
url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Clean_Bandit_-_Solo_(feat._Demi_Lovato)_(Latin_Remix).mp3',
title: 'Solo (Latin Remix)',
artist: 'Clean Bandit feat. Demi Lovato',
},
{
id: '4',
url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Greyson_Chance_-_Waiting_Outside_The_Lines.mp3',
title: 'Waiting Outside The Lines',
artist: 'Greyson Chance',
artwork: ''
},
];

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return <Player tracks={TRACKS} />
  }
}
```

Comment: my ?? wow at least give some credit for their work ...

Answer (score 0):

If you got autoPlay variable(I got that in redux) , then just check below condition for auto play.

```
 if(this.props.autoPlay){
       if( this.state.currentPosition >= this.state.totalLength ){
          this.onForward();
       }
    }
```